# Resize special character CSS content

Tags: css, special-characters

Is that possible to re-size the special character CSS content? Original size is too big for me, I tried using height and width but not affect.

```
.icon-arrow:before {
    content: '\25BC';
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `font-size` to achieve that, because special symbols (for example unicode) have the same behavior as any other character [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6zz8jLdq/)

```
.icon-arrow:before {
    content: '\25BC';
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers are correct, but I would like to add that I prefer to use `em` to size characters in this way. This will size the character relative to the font-size of the parent element.

For example:

`font-size:0.9em`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
font-size: (....)px;
```